# Button not shown in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have one list view and one button in my relative layout.

It shown in Eclipse graphical view. But in emulator listview only show.
Button not shown in emulator.

**My XML code here**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="415dp" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="submit"
    android:text="SUBMIT" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My manifest code**

```
 <uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="14"
 android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


 <activity android:name="com.androidexample.tabbar.Tab1"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
 </activity>
```

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I erase my old code and create a new relative layout then now works fine.

Cause of error is **I convert the Linear layout to Relative layout manually**.

my code after modification is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="420dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:onClick="submit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above=@"+id/button1" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="submit"
    android:text="SUBMIT" />
```